# Why stepper motor power supply fluctuates

Tags: stepper

I am driving stepper motor using Raspberry Pi 3. I am using stepper motor driver Pololu A4988. A driver has potentiometer which we can adjust to provide specified current to the motor. My stepper motor current rating is 1 Amp and I am using 12 V 3 A power supply, but still when I start the motor power supply fluctuates. Even while using a 12V 5A power supply, the same problem is occurring. Please, Help and provide the solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is NOT a Software Development related question. It could belong here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, Peter B. Is this platform is only for software development related questions? I don't think so.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: `Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers...
# a specific programming problem, or # a software algorithm, or # software tools commonly used by programmers; and is # a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!` Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are related however.